# Merge featurecollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, merge, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, features, string

If I have several featurecollections in GEE, I can merge them quickly. However, if I have 1000 featurecollections, whether it means I need to type 999 'merge' in code. I think it is too time-consuming. I have try a way that uses string cat, but it did not work and just print string like 'table2'. So how can I merge them quickly through for loop or other ways?
The picture below is my situation, the tables in the asset are collected by my teammates. I need to import them firstly.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you should not use `merge()`, because it is not meant for that. Instead, use [`flatten()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-flatten) which turns a collection of collections into a collection.

First, get all of your collections *into a* `FeatureCollection`, then call `.flatten()` on that. If you have variables then that would look like:

```rust
var merged = ee.FeatureCollection([
    table1,
    table2, 
    // et cetera
    table1000,
]).flatten();
```

However, having 1000 variables is *also* be a sign that something is wrong. As a general rule in any kind of programming, not just Earth Engine: if you have to write extremely repetitive code, then there is a mistake somewhere. Look at the process that *produced* the 1000 things, and find a way to do it differently or automatically.

In your case, you have 1000 separate table assets. Fix the process that created them so that you have the data in fewer table assets. Or, if you really have to, you can write a loop that loads the assets (assuming they are systematically named). That's a different topic, though, so please post a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This way do not need to use 'merge'. However, it is still very time-consuming. I have added a picture to discrible my situation.

Comment: @wwllpp Then, I would say that the trouble started when 1000 separate table assets were created. Try not to end up in that situation. (Updated my answer.)